# How can I edit the Woocommerce product widget html class?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I would like to add a class to the existing woocommerce product widget.

The file `'/includes/widgets/class-wc-widget-products.php'` has the following filter.

```
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_before_widget_product_list', '<ul class="product_list_widget">' );
```

Is there a method that I can edit the html `<ul class="product_list_widget">` in that filter within my theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems to be straight. Add the following in your `functions.php`

```
add_filter( "woocommerce_before_widget_product_list", "edit_product_widget_list", 1, 1 );

//$old_html contains -> <ul class="product_list_widget">
function edit_product_widget_list ( $old_html ) {
    return '<ul class="my_own_class_here">'; // change your class here
}
```

Good luck :)

Comment: Brilliant, really simple to do! I'll be sure to make use of add_filter now :) Thanks.